# how to toggle the value of a int variable

Tags: swift, integer, toggle, var, alternate

I want to use a toggle to change the value of int var punch card from 0 to 1. I am pretty sure there is a way to alternate this. I know it uses the : but I have forgotten it. It would also be cool if you could alternate between 0 1 2. I would think that is pretty easy once you get the 0  and 1 to work.

```
 var punchCard = 0

        @objc func memephis(){
        punchCard : 0: 1
        
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean you want it to be set to 1 if it is 0, and be set to 0 if it is 1?

Comment: Are you looking for the ternary-operator? https://www.hackingwithswift.com/sixty/3/7/the-ternary-operator

Comment: @HarryJ yes could you provide a answer with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can combat your issue. You *could* use a Boolean value & get it's integer value as they can be converted to 0 (false) or 1 (true).

```
var punchCard: Bool = true // 1
punchCard.toggle() // Will change between the value
print(punchCard.intValue) // 0

extension Bool {
    var intValue: Int {
        return self ? 1 : 0
    }
}
```

However you could too use a [ternary-operator](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/sixty/3/7/the-ternary-operator).

```
var punchCard = 0

func memephis() {
   punchCard = punchCard == 0 ? 1 : 0
}
```

Comment: how would i use a ternary operator for 3 values

Comment: Your question becomes obsolete when adding in another parameter. The logic, and use cases also change significantly. Not preferred, nor easy with the use of a ternary operator.